# Link Prediction on Directed Graph using node embedding

Tags: machine-learning, graph-theory

I am trying to solve the link prediction problem in a directed graph using supervised learning.

In the case of an undirected graph, it is pretty straightforward. For instance, first, compute the embeddings and solve the problem as a binary classification problem, where, node embeddings need to be transformed into edge embeddings by averaging or adding ‘i’ and ‘j’ node embeddings. This makes sense in an undirected graph because i->j and j->i edges represent the same link.

However, in a directed graph, it doesn’t make sense to transform the node embedding pair into edge embedding by adding or average. Can anyone help me out on how I can convert the node embedding into edge embedding?

Comment: Why not concatenate them? [head, tail]

Comment: Thanks, @AryaMcCarthy for the suggestion Let me try it and get back to you